# Regular Expression to remove single characters from the beginning of string, only if there are 2 or more

Tags: php, regex

I'm devastatingly miserable at complex regular expressions, but I would love a nudge in the right direction. I'm trying to parse some authors' names by removing initials, when the full names are used later. I realize there probably won't be a "perfect" solution that catches all exceptions, but I'm looking for a "good enough" solution.

Example input

```
C S Clive Staples Lewis
T H Terence Hanbury White
R Salvatore
George R R Martin
J R R John Ronald Reuel Tolkien
J K Rowling
```

Ideal output

```
Clive Staples Lewis
Terence Hanbury White
R Salvatore
George R R Martin
John Ronald Reuel Tolkien
J K Rowling
```

Something along the lines of this: `$str = preg_replace('#(?:\s+\S{1,2})+\s+#',' ',$str);` though this is obviously missing the first instance of the single character, but changing that would remove the r in r salvatore and the j k in j k rowling.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: using the above regex, the `K` and the `H` do get removed. I was using them to see if there is a way to catch these edge cases where in the Terence Hanbury situation I would want then removed. while in the case of J K Rowling, I'd like them to stay. The only thing I could think of is using pretty complex logic to count the number of single, leading initials, then check the following # of words to see if they begin with the same letters, and if so, remove them. Not too efficient.

Comment: Though not working for unlimited counts, I have come up with a regex that does that exact check (look for name starting with that initial) in my answer below. Hopefully it does enough for you.

Comment: No worries - out of interest, what language was this for? PHP/JavaScript/Python? Anubhava has added `php` as a tag, but your other questions have all been tagged python..

Comment: "Devastatingly miserable at complex regular expressions". Only on Stackoverflow will you ever see that combination of words. Love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^(?:([A-Z])(?=.*?\1[a-z]+)\s)+
```

It will match:

```
^ // from the beginning of the string
(?:  // non-capturing group
    ([A-Z]) // cature uppercase string
    (?=.*?\1[a-z]+) // positive lookahead for the letter captured above followed by multiple lowercase characters
    \s // followed by a space
)+ // multiple times
```

[php live regex example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1qJ)

Comment: for simplicity, in-depth explanation, and using syntax i can use in PHP.

Comment: This doesn't check the order btw, which could have adverse affects on certain names, e.g. Stuart John Smith written as 'S John Smith' would wrongly have the 'S ' at the beginning removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this:

```
$str = 'C S Clive Staples Lewis';    
$str = preg_replace('#^([A-Z]\s)+(?=([A-Z]+\s+){2,})#i','',$str); 
echo $str; // Clive Staples Lewis

$str = 'J K Rowling';    
$str = preg_replace('#^([A-Z]\s)+(?=([A-Z]+\s+){2,})#i','',$str); 
echo $str; // J K Rowling
```

Comment: This fails on "R Salvatore" where the full first name does not appear.

Comment: @Max: I have to delete my answer since rules aren't clear about `R Salvatore` OR `J K Rowling`

Comment: @Max: Please check the edit now and note that OP wrote `I'm looking for a "good enough" solution`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~^(?:[A-Z]\h){2,}~m', '', $str);
```

If you want to put exceptions you can do that:

```
$str = <<<LOD
C S Clive Staples Lewis
T H Terence Hanbury White
R Salvatore
George R R Martin
J R R John Ronald Reuel Tolkien
J K Rowling
J F Kennedy
C P E Bach
LOD;

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
  # definitions

  (?(DEFINE)
    (?<exceptions>  J \h K \h      Rowling
                  | J \h F \h      Kennedy
                  | C \h P \h E \h Bach
    )
  )

  # pattern

  ^(?!\g<exceptions>)
  (?:[A-Z]\h){2,}
~xm
LOD;

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you're after:

```
var t = [
'C S Clive Staples Lewis'
,'T H Terence Hanbury White'
,'R Salvatore'
,'George R R Martin'
,'J R R John Ronald Reuel Tolkien'
,'J K Rowling'
];
for(var i=0,c=t.length;i<c;i++)
{
    var newStr = t[i].replace(/^([A-Z]) ([A-Z])((?: [A-Z])?) (\1\w+ \2\w+( \3\w+)?.+)$/,'$4');
    console.log(newStr);
}

/*
Results:

Clive Staples Lewis
Terence Hanbury White
R Salvatore
George R R Martin
John Ronald Reuel Tolkien
J K Rowling

*/
```

Do note, however, that this method is limited to 3 initials (though I can't see you ever having more than that!)

On the plus side, this is checking that initials are matched up to a name starting with that letter before removing them

**If you need PHP:**

```
$t = array(
'C S Clive Staples Lewis'
,'T H Terence Hanbury White'
,'R Salvatore'
,'George R R Martin'
,'J R R John Ronald Reuel Tolkien'
,'J K Rowling'
);
for($i=0,$c=count($t);$i<$c;$i++)
{
    $newStr = preg_replace('/^([A-Z]) ([A-Z])((?: [A-Z])?) (\1\w+ \2\w+( \3\w+)?.+)$/','$4',$t[$i]);
    var_dump($newStr);
}
```

Comment: lots of "good enough" solutions, but this one does, indeed, pass all of my test cases so far. Thank you.

Comment: @sosukeinu No problem - glad to have helped. I've added a PHP alternative to my test code, just in case that's what you're working with (no language mentioned in question)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

> (?(^(\w\s)+\w{2,}(\s\w{2,}){1,})^(\w\s)+)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using PHP you did not specify a language. So this is a sample in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $data_fh, '<', 'Data1.txt' 
    or die "Can't open Data1.txt $!";

while (my $line = <$data_fh>) {
    $line =~ s/\b([A-Z])\b (?=.*?\b\1[A-Z]+\b)//xig; # Match an initial only if there is a word starting with that initial later in the string.
    $line =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//g; #strip leading or trailing space.
    print "$line\n";
}

#OUTPUT
Clive Staples Lewis
Terence Hanbury White
R Salvatore
George R R Martin
John Ronald Reuel Tolkien
J K Rowling
```